# Export List of lists as a FeatureCollection (CSV) in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, csv, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, list

I need to export CSV but my input is a **list of lists** so I have an error *"FeatureCollection (Error)
List.get: Parameter 'list' is required."* How can I change my input data? Or the export mode?

````
var mod = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD11A1');
var point = ee.Geometry.Point(-116.0199,36.62418);
var buffer = point.buffer(564.2);
var collection = mod.filterBounds(buffer)
                    .filterDate('2022-01-01', '2023-01-01')
                    .select(['LST_Day_1km', 'Day_view_time']);
//print(collection.size());
//Map.centerObject(point, 6);
//Map.addLayer(point);
var filtered_scaled = collection.map(function(image) {
var buffer = point.buffer(564.2);
var time = image.select('Day_view_time').multiply(0.1).add(8).copyProperties(image);
var lst = image.select('LST_Day_1km').multiply(0.02).copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start', 'system:index']);
return image.addBands(time, null, true)
              .addBands(lst, null, true)
              .clip(buffer)});
              
var nImages = filtered_scaled.size();
var ImageList = filtered_scaled.toList(nImages);
var img_indices = ee.List.sequence(0,nImages.subtract(1)).getInfo();

function reduceAndPrint(index) {
  var nomScale = filtered_scaled.select('LST_Day_1km').first().projection().nominalScale();
  var nomScale2 = filtered_scaled.select('Day_view_time').first().projection().nominalScale();
  var buffer = point.buffer(564.2); // CALCULATION LST BUFFER
  var image = ee.Image(ImageList.get(index));
  
  var TmeanDay = image.select('Day_view_time').reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    maxPixels: 1e9,
    scale: nomScale2,
    geometry: buffer
  });    

  var time = TmeanDay.get('Day_view_time');
   //print(time);
    //print('time', time);
  var hours = ee.Number(time).floor().divide(1).int();
  var minutes = ee.Number(time).subtract(hours).multiply(60).round().int();
  var result = hours.format('%02d').cat(':').cat(minutes.format('%02d')).cat(':00');
      
  var systemTimeStart = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd ');
  var sts = ee.String(systemTimeStart).cat(ee.String(result));
  //print('sts:', sts);
  var date = image.get('system:index');
  return ee.Algorithms.If(time, [image.id(), sts, date], null);
      } 
      
var stats = img_indices.map(reduceAndPrint); 

//print(stats);

var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(stats.map(function(list) {
    list = ee.List(list);
    var dict = {
        
        a_image_id:            list.get(0),   
        b_Day_view_time:       list.get(1),   
        c_date:                list.get(2),    
    };
  return ee.Feature(null, dict);
}));

print(fc);
// Export.table.toDrive({
//   collection: wholeYearFC,
//   description: 'DesertRock_Modis',
//   fileFormat: 'CSV',
//   folder:'ResultsFromGEE'
// });```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your issue by using following lines instead:

```
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(stats.map(function(list) {
    list = ee.List(list);
    var dict = {
        
        a_image_id:            list.get(0),   
        b_Day_view_time:       list.get(1),   
        c_date:                list.get(2),    
    };
  
  return ee.Algorithms.If(list, ee.Feature(null, dict), null);

}));

print(fc);
Export.table.toDrive({
   collection: fc,
   description: 'DesertRock_Modis',
   fileFormat: 'CSV',
   folder:'ResultsFromGEE'
 });
```

After running [complete code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9b887af372308f1e2daca7f19b28f25a) (where it was also avoided the use of **getInfo**), I got following CSV:

[image]

Comment: You should work in my university! :) After 2 weeks of trying to make my script work, finally it does! And not more 10 minutes waiting for server response. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have some entries in your list with `null`; thus, when your function `fc` tries to `get` elements from that `null` it results in an error. An easy solution is to simply filter the List to get rid of the `null` entries, before getting the values and setting them as properties of a Feature. Here is the only change you need to make.

```
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(
          // Filter to retain not null entries
          ee.List(stats).filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['item']))
               .map(function(list) {
                 list = ee.List(list);
                 var dict = {
                   a_image_id: list.get(0),   
                   b_Day_view_time: list.get(1),   
                   c_date: list.get(2),    
                   };
                return ee.Feature(null, dict);
               }));
```

Comment: I'm really grateful for your explanation coz it's important to understand the meanings of these things and how they works! Thank you.